# Real depth of field in blender, without post processing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, depth-of-field

Last time I checked, blender could only render depth of field effects in a post process pass, using the "Defocus Node", which seemed to get it quite wrong.

Is there now a way to include rays across a lens during tracing and produce a more realistic depth of field?

Comment: Related: [2S vs 3D DoF](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7395/2d-vs-3d-depth-of-field?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With the Cycles Renderer, DoF is supported natively. Select the camera, switch to the Camera properties panel, and set up DoF.

[image: DoF properties]

Answer (score 2):

Also you must use a real size object to obtain realistic result (to get a reliable f/stop response, like real world lenses). Small objects close up (at a short focal length) make a great bokeh effect due to a shallow DoF. Larger, distant objects like a building create poor bokeh (deep DoF).
Also play with some camera presets, like sensor size and focal length.