# How to change camera focus in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

I want to ask, is it possible to change camera focus in Blender? For example, I want the camera to focus to an object. So the other objects behind the focused object have a blur effect. How to do that?
Thanks for the reply :D

Comment: I think you should search for depth of field setting, it would be easier to find already answered questions here on SE - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/depth-of-field-in-2-68

Comment: compositor: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/blender-cycles-manual-dof, cycles: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/real-depth-of-field-in-blender-without-post-processing/7925#7925

Comment: If the links/answers doesn't solve your issue, leave a comment here or edit your question. Note: Since 2.74 you can preview dof in the viewport, see the release notes: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.74/UI