# What causes these artifacts around the edges of objects when using the defocus node?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

Continuing on with the same logo reveal. The depth of field in Blender results in this horrible effect around the edge. I've seen this sort of blurring a lot in games, Assassin's Creed is quite famous for it.

The focused object shouldn't make this strange outline and I need the edges to look properly blurred and transition nicely into whatever's behind it without this strange effect seen around the square in the top right.

Apologies for the low shading samples.

[image]

[image]

Just tried it in Cycles. The lighting looks a lot better as usual however the same effect is still happening. I've tried both 'radius' and 'f/stop'. Radius being the same and f/stop creating this crazy blur.

Radius

[image]

f/stop
[image]

The blurred cubes still have sharp edges alongside a blurry outline. 
[image]

Comment: Try using cycles's built in DoF, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7395/599

Comment: Just tried, and have made an update.

Comment: I don't actually see anything which looks wrong to me, aside from the overly huge aperture in the last render.. Could you highlight what looks off to you?

Comment: Updated it showing the sharp edges on the blurred cubes.

Comment: Do you still have the compositing nodes from before? If that's not it, is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: I do yes, and I've set them close to what they were like in that other thread just with a higher f/stop in the defocus node. As it's a company project I can't send any file but I'll upload pictures of all the settings now.

Comment: Try removing the defocus node. Using two separate DoF methods at once is not needed, and my  guess is that those edges are caused by the defocus node.

Comment: Try using only the depth of field on the camera only ( without the defocus node.)

Comment: Yes that worked! It's a shame though as it was a lot easier being able to set it in nodes without having to constantly render. I don't use Cycles a lot so could you possibly tell me how to up the quality so that I don't have the noise?

Comment: use more samples. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/how-to-reduce-noise-in-cycles-render

Comment: previewing the depth of field of the camera in cycles is quite easy if you use **Rendered** shading in the 3D view window (press shift Z to enable)

Answer (score 3):

I've sometimes had odd results with the defocus node, particularly with large aperture sizes. See [2d vs 3d Depth of Field](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7395/599).

Try using [built in Cycles DoF](http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/camera.html?#depth-of-field), which [simulates the way light behaves](http://www.diyphotography.net/can-you-make-computerized-shaped-bokeh/) at a lower level. It gives realistic and seamless results without requiring any fussing with the Z buffer:

[image]

The only downside is the inability to edit it in post.