# How to create a realistic glass material similar to this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, glass, hdri

I'm trying to create a molecular scene similar to this:

[image]

I have attached here my blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GFdbRQH5UCvOVWDJdgBlhnNIdrRgqhwV/view?usp=sharing

I have difficulty in creating the background. Even though I added environment texture with an HDRI image, I tried several types of glass material, but the result is this:

[image]

Comment: Hi :). You just need waaay more contrast in lighting (or in hdri).

Comment: I think it's because your back plane has an emission shader component - removing it should resolve the glass somewhat. Also, the correct IOR for glass is 1.450 - yours is lowered to 1.10 (if there's some reason for that, then skip this, but I think its influencing what you're seeing). Lastly (though its not a huge difference), since you are using cycles, you can skip the Principled BSDF and just use a Glass BSDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did a good job with the models (sphere + *Solidify* modifier), environment, and the shader.

As already mentioned in the comments you just need to tweak a few things.

[image]
<sup>The bad white points are from a point light / Only camera Depth of Field with 2000 samples (adaptive)</sup>

1. the ***IOR*** for glass is `1.450`. This creates the distortion if you look through the glass sphere and affects the reflection on it
2. to get a tint for the glass add some ***Volume Absorption***. With the *Solidify* modifier this creates a darker tint. It's the same effect that you see at the side of the plate of a glass table for example.
3. use an **HDRI** with a bumped boosted strength and **a big environment box**. The HDRI you have already. The beveled plane that you use for the background and the HDR image will be reflected in the spheres. If you want to have a "clean look" as in the reference you need to reduce the reflects a bit with a big "shield". This will also create shadows and of course, requires more light => HDRI strength `4 or 5`. Note that when the environment box is too close it will tint the sphere. Scale it up a lot if you don't want this.
4. optional, if you want to enhance the silhouette/the rim of the glass you can add a ***Layered Weight*** node with a *Color Ramp* to darken the rim a bit.
5. Last but not least, you can increase the contrast in the *Render Properties > **Color Management*** settings to `Medium High Contrast` or `High Contrast`

Please note that the rendered result heavily depends on the used HDRI!

For the composition of the scene I recommend using *Linked* objects, and *Collection Instances* for the molecules.

**Model Setup**

The box is 250 m large. Don't forget the adjust the camera's clipping (*Lens > Clip End*).
[image: model]

**Glass Shader**

[image: glass shader]

**Examples (128 samples, adaptive)**

Beveled plane as background/environment = more reflections, [noisy camera DOF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67437/107598)

[image: beveled plane]

For comparison: the glass spheres have no layered color but the connections have. Used the *Defocus* node for depth of field effect

[image: no layered color]

Different HDRIs result in different colors:

[image: greenish]