# I have heard that you can focus the camera in Blender Cycles, but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

I want to be able to have the camera focus on a certain person or object (you know like when stuff in the background is blurry but the stuff in front is clear. I have tried many different things including enabling four min the camera and choosing the object to focus on, and creating an empty and setting the focus on that then placing it on what I want it to focus on). Does anyone know any better way to do that.

Comment: Make sure you are looking through you camera ("0" on num pad) in rendered view (shift+Z) then select your camera, go to camera icon, under depth of field choose your empty or any object that you want to be in focus, then change the size setting next to it to your liking.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32861/how-to-create-bokeh-circles/32863#32863 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/blender-cycles-manual-dof or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7395/2d-vs-3d-depth-of-field

Comment: Thanks @icYou520, I have tried just that, but it doesn't quite work the way I wanted. When I have the size at 4, the Suzanne heads in the back are nice and blurry like I wanted, but the one to be focused on is way to blurry. When I set the size way down, like (.1 or so), the focus one is great again, but then practically everything else in the scene is visible.